# How to make infinite each_with_object actually lazy?

Tags: ruby

**tl;dr**

I expect both of those lines to return `{:a => 10}`

```
p (0..5).each_with_object({a: 0}) { |i, acc| acc[:a] += i}
p (0..Float::INFINITY).lazy.each_with_object({a: 0}) { |i, acc| acc[:a] += i}.first(5)
```

However, the second line loops forever.

**Longer version**

This example is of course simplified whilst the real problem is very similar. The idea is to run `each_with_object` body until certain condition is met, however this condition relies on result that this very `each_with_object` function generates over each iteration so the stop condition must come *after* `each_with_object`.

The closest I could get was

```
p (0..Float::INFINITY).lazy.each_with_object({a: 0}).take_while{ |i, acc| acc[:a] += i}.first(5)
```

but the result is not exactly what I want as it returns the following

```
[[0, {:a=>10}], [1, {:a=>10}], [2, {:a=>10}], [3, {:a=>10}], [4, {:a=>10}]]
```

which not only forces me to do `.last.last` but also makes the array grow immensely as I iterate many times (and also it stores 5 times the `{:a => 10}` instead of `{a:=>0}, {a:=>1}, {a:=>3}, ...` which is also a mystery to me.

Comment: Not a lazy enumerator, but you can use `break` with a value to exit an infinite loop, e.g. `0.step.each_with_object({a: 0}) { |i, acc| acc[:a] += i; break acc if i == 5 }`

Comment: That's sort of workaround. Surprisingly execution time remained pretty much the same..

Comment: _"condition relies on result that this very `each_with_object` function generates"_ – you should modify your example accordingly.

Comment: "Returns a lazy enumerator, whose methods map/collect, flat_map/collect_concat, select/find_all, reject, grep, #grep_v, zip, take, #take_while, drop, and #drop_while enumerate values only on an as-needed basis. However, if a block is given to zip, values are enumerated immediately." no mention of `each_with_object` having a lazy implementation which is most likely why your second example loops forever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`each_with_object` only returns an enumerator if you don't pass a block.

Maybe you could create your own method:

```
class Enumerator::Lazy
  def my_each_with_object(obj)
    Lazy.new(self) do |yielder, *args|
      yield *args, obj
      yielder << obj
    end
  end
end

(1..Float::INFINITY).lazy
                    .my_each_with_object({a: 0}) { |i, acc| acc[:a] += i }
                    .drop_while { |acc| acc[:a] <= 10 }
                    .first
#=> {:a=>15}
```

I've used `acc[:a] <= 10` as a condition because you said that it depends on the value calculated by `each_with_object`.